# SSHA512 generating hash in c# for Postfix

Tags: c#, hash, ssha

I have to generate password hash with SSHA512 which could work with Postfix.
I have hash generator written in Python and i need to rewrite it to C#.
I wrote some code in c# that generating hash but Postfix could not verify generated password.

Python code:

```
def generate_ssha512_password(p):
"""Generate salted SHA512 password with prefix '{SSHA512}'.
Return SSHA instead if python is older than 2.5 (not supported in module hashlib)."""
p = str(p).strip()
try:
    from hashlib import sha512
    salt = os.urandom(8)
    pw = sha512(p)
    pw.update(salt)
    return '{SSHA512}' + b64encode(pw.digest() + salt)
```

And My C# code version 1:

```
        public static string CreateSalt(int size)
    {
        //Generate a cryptographic random number.
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buff = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
    }
        public static string GenerateHash(string input, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
        SHA512 sHA512ManagedString = new SHA512Managed();
        byte[] hash = sHA512ManagedString.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
```

C# code version 2:

```
        public static byte[] CreateSaltRaw(int size)
    {
        //Generate a cryptographic random number.
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buff = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        return buff;
    }
    public static string GenerateHash2(string input, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + Convert.ToBase64String(salt));
        SHA512 sHA512ManagedString = new SHA512Managed();
        byte[] hash = sHA512ManagedString.ComputeHash(bytes);
        List<byte> pass = hash.ToList();
        foreach (var s in salt)
        {
            pass.Add(s);
        }
        //return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(pass.ToArray());
    }
```

In version 1 generated hash is shorten than hash generated in Python.
In version 2 length is same.
Unfortunetly both versions doesn't work in Postfix. Generated hash can't be verified.

Values i get:

Password: texas

Python generated password:

```
Q5RlBLOCizu/o/iI7NrzqI1lIvMJ5lLngPH1zdeYSdbA+G+wzNcCTwPOwEG/oKM5P3bqrBcm5gLDSdBO3IjnplWHbgqgTBvV
```

C#:

raw salt values v1:

```
0xed 0x01 0x97 0x7b 0xc2 0xec 0x29 0x76
```

encoded salt v1:

```
7Q+Xe8LsKXY=
```

encode salt + pass v1 :

```
2EXXraKRShKwOOb9TYU4hoXVQPhhujaK2dJVe8/n423tW3dOBBdycUPBluMmRtkNELIocAIkRKR6Rk+R5T43rw==
```

Comment: Can you provide a base64-encoded sample input and base64-encoded salt, and the results of using those values for each of the 3 sample codes?

Comment: If you're wondering why I'm asking for this, it's so I (and others) don't have to go away and figure out how to get your Python code to compile.

Comment: Can you edit the question with that, please?

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look in a minute if nobody else beats me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the posted result of the Python code

```
Q5RlBLOCizu/o/iI7NrzqI1lIvMJ5lLngPH1zdeYSdbA+G+wzNcCTwPOwEG/oKM5P3bqrBcm5gLDSdBO3IjnplWHbgqgTBvV
```

the following can be derived as salt after Base64 decoding:

```
55876e0aa04c1bd5 (hex encoded) or VYduCqBMG9U= (Base64 encoded)
```

In the C# code, first salt and password must be encoded:

```
byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String("VYduCqBMG9U="); 
byte[] password = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("texas"); // Here the encoding of the Python code must be used
```

Before hashing, both `byte[]` must be concatenated. Since the concatenation of `byte[]` is needed again later, it's useful to implement a helper method:

```
private static byte[] join(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[b1.Length + b2.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(b1, 0, b, 0, b1.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(b2, 0, b, b1.Length, b2.Length);
    return b;
}
```

Thus the hashing is performed as follows:

```
HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA512Managed();
byte[] passwordSalt = join(password, salt);
byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(passwordSalt);
```

Before the Base64 encoding, hash and salt must be concatenated:

```
byte[] hashSalt = join(hash, salt);
string hashSaltB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hashSalt); // Q5RlBLOCizu/o/iI7NrzqI1lIvMJ5lLngPH1zdeYSdbA+G+wzNcCTwPOwEG/oKM5P3bqrBcm5gLDSdBO3IjnplWHbgqgTBvV
```

To process a random salt you can use e.g. your `CreateSaltRaw` method and simply replace

```
byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String("VYduCqBMG9U=");
```

by

```
byte[] salt = CreateSaltRaw(8);
```